# Is there a more convenient key binding for RETURN?

Tags: key-bindings

Navigation with C-n, C-p etc. is quite easy in emacs, but I have to stretch my hand a lot to hit RETURN.

Is there another standard key binding with the same effect as the RETURN key?

---

background of my question:

I discovered that in many applications (like e. g. Safari on MacOS X) at least some of the motion commands of emacs do work, e. g. C-n and C-p, C-a and C-e. 
As using the arrow keys forces me to leave the normal hands position during typing, I find it really helpful to use those instead of the arrow keys, e. g. for typing an address in the URL field of the Safari browser and then cycling to the matching suggestions of Safari:

[image: screenshot URL selection]

Thats really cool, but then I have to stretch my pinky or move my hand to hit RETURN to select one of those, so I wondered if there might be a hidden way of directly going to the selected URL.

It seems that it is not yet defined, but I will try to define `C-m` to get an Emacs-compatible key-binding also in Safari.

Even cooler: with the [**Type-to-navigate** extension](http://dbergey.github.io/) I can type some characters and then can cycle through the found occurrences on the open web page with Cmd-G and then (again with RETURN) directly open a URL which contains this text.. navigation without the mouse is very helpful for me. But again, RETURN forces me to leave the normal hands position on my keyboard a little.

Comment: Did you try`C-m`?

Comment: sorry for being not very precise: see my added explication

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`C-m` should have the same effect, `C-j` and `M-j` come close, but do subtly different things depending on your active modes and configuration, such as indenting the current line.